# Is there a a way in Ruby to increment a Struct object variable inside an array?

Tags: ruby

```
Namepoints = Struct.new(:name, :points)

def arraytesting2()

  x = Namepoints.new("Seasons", 1)
  array = []
  255.times do

    unless array.include? x.name
      array << x.name
      array << x.points
    else
      array[array.index(x.points) + 1 ]
    end
  end
  print array.to_s.gsub(/[\[\]"]/, "")
end

arraytesting2
```

Outcome: Seasons, 1

Expected outcome: Seasons, 255

`array[array.index(x.points) + 1 ]` will not increment?

Also attempting this another way: `array[array.index(x.points + 1 )]` receives a conversion error

Comment: This feels like an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do? Are you trying to sum the points of seasons with the same name? Are you trying to count the seasons with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s easier to use `Array#index` rather than `Array#include?`.

```rb
Namepoints = Struct.new(:name, :points)

def arraytesting2(x)
  255.times.each_with_object([]) do |_, array|
    if found = array.index(x.name)
      array[found + 1] += 1 # points are right after
    else
      array << x.name << x.points
    end
  end
end

arraytesting2(Namepoints.new("Seasons", 1))
#⇒ ["Seasons", 255]
```

Comment: You can simplify: `def arraytesting2(x) [x.name, x.points + 254] end`.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to increment the value of an array found at a given index.

The index being `array.index(x.points)`.

You can do that by:

```rb
array[array.index(x.points)] += 1
```

What your code was doing was access the value of the index found after `array.index(x.points)`:

```rb
array[array.index(x.points) + 1]
```

---

However, note that this still won't print

> Seasons, 255

Reason being that after the first iteration, the array will hold:

```
['Seasons', 2]
```

And the namepoints value of points is still `1`. So next time you search for `1`, you will not find it.

---

To fix this, it depends a bit on what you're trying to achieve. Either increment the value in namepoints as well or use a hash instead of an array. I'm not clear on why you needed the array.